# Is it save to include AWS Cognito Identity Pool ID when pushing to github

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am making an app that will use AWS services as backend.  I want to push the code to github.  I know that shouldn't push any code with credentials embedded. 
After reading this article https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2XEKZCNBM7U64/How-Amazon-Cognito-Keeps-Mobile-App-Users-Data-Safe i think it should be safe to have IdentityPoolID in the source code.  I searched github and i seen many files with ID included in them.  Is there anything can be done with the ID that compromises my AWS account?  Should i just create .h files and add that file in .gitignore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never be sure if it safe to commit this to GitHub but I'd like to raise another concern. When you Open Source an application, you ideally want someone else to be able to obtain a copy and install it to match their needs. That means there shouldn't be any configuration parts for your setup but there should be general file with example strings.

That being said, I recommend you do the `.gitignore` solution and `add -f` a default `.h` file.

Answer (score 4):

It is safe in the sense that nobody can steal your identity (your AWS acount details, access keys and secret keys). But developers who download your app from GitHub and run it will access ***your*** AWS services via Cognito. Your account will be charged for that. And of course you should take care which other AWS privileges are associated with the Cognito roles. I have an [AWS open source project on GitHub](https://github.com/peterfennema/AmazonSwiftStarter) and I don’t publish any AWS identifiers at all.